# Can't install gdm linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, gnome

I am switching from default linux mint to gnome. However, when attempting to install the gnome desktop manager on Linux Mint XFCE 19, I experienced this error:

```
lukaka@SetLucas-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install gdm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gdm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gdm' has no installation candidate
lukaka@SetLucas-PC:~$
```

How can I install gdm?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realize `gdm` is outdated, and I needed to install `gdm3` instead.

```
lukaka@SetLucas-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install gdm3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cdparanoia cdrdao cdrskin k3b-data libk3b7 libkf5cddb-data libkf5cddb5
  libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5notifyconfig5 libllvm6.0:i386
  libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 linux-headers-4.15.0-34 linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic
  linux-headers-4.15.0-36 linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-34-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-36-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-36-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  libpam-fprintd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gdm3
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 56 not upgraded.
Need to get 268 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,815 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gdm3 amd64 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4 [268 kB]
Fetched 268 kB in 0s (2,011 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package gdm3.
(Reading database ... 515287 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gdm3_3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gdm3 (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up gdm3 (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4) ...

Creating config file /etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults with new version
gdm.service is not active, cannot reload.
invoke-rc.d: initscript gdm3, action "reload" failed.
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.21) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
lukaka@SetLucas-PC:~$
```

Comment: Is there a way to install gdm3 without all the Gnome3 and Ubuntu dependencies. I'm running Linux Mint 20.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way I'm afraid.